# How to add a login page to Nebular ngx-admin without using any neb auth module?

Tags: ngx-admin

I am struck in showing my own login page component in nebular ngx-admin project .,always it's redirecting to home page..if someone had included any login page  please me the steps u did to create your own component and how included in ngx-admin without using Nebular auth module...I have redirected the path also in app.routing.module but still it is getting to home page of ngx-admin and not able to show login page..If I comment my home page redirection in app routing modulethe spinner is keep on loading ..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

could you please post your routing here? Regarding the ngx-admin routing, it's enough just to replace `NbAuthComponent` with your custom component. You even don't need to modify routing for that.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'pages', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule' },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: NbAuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: NbLoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: NbLoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: NbRegisterComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'logout',
        component: NbLogoutComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'request-password',
        component: NbRequestPasswordComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'reset-password',
        component: NbResetPasswordComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response..I am nwebie and just using the themes module  alone from ngx-admin..I have not used auth module at all ..anyway I can able to solve the the same by 1)adding login routing in app.routing.module instead of pages.module .                         2)have also removed the theme spinner which worked for me(otherwise it's keep on loading) and can able to redirect to own login page.